# Dataset to JSON tree by merging

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, c#-4.0, serialization

Say I have the below Dataset.

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╗
║  Category   ║     Item      ║ Color ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╣
║ Electronics ║ Mobile        ║ Black ║
║ Electronics ║ Mobile        ║ Green ║
║ Electronics ║ Laptop        ║ Black ║
║ HomeNeeds   ║ VaccumCleaner ║ white ║
║ HomeNeeds   ║ Refrigerator  ║ Red   ║
║ Wearable    ║ AppleWatch    ║ Red   ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

I want to transform this into SOMETHING like below JSON format so that I can load into a treeview control. What will be the best way to do that? The main difference is merging the same category or items! 
I can parse node to node in C#, check it with the previous node, merge it if it is same! and create it manually, but is there any other alternative instead of this long and complex process?

```
{
    "Categories" : [
        {"Electronics" : [
                {"Mobile" : [
                    {"color":"Black"},
                    {"color":"Green"}
                    ]},
                {"Laptop":[
                    {"color":"Black"}
                    ]}
            ]},
        {"HomeNeeds":[
            {"VaccumCleaner": [
                    {"color":"white"}
                ]},
            {"Refrigerator":[
                {"color": "Red"}
                ]}
            ]},
        {"Wearable":[
            {"Applewatch":[
                {"color":"Red"}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an array.

```
var products = new Array(); // using new Array() to avoid mess

   products = 
    [
        [ // Home Needs
            [
                "Refrigerator",
                "red",
                "$500",
            ],
            [
                "VacuumCleaner",
                "white",
                "$50",
            ]
        ],
        [ // Wearable
            [
                "Applewatch",
                "Red",
                "$14, 000",
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

Here is an example on how you would use this.

```
function getInfoOn(category,nameofappliance) { // 0 for category is home needs, etc
    for (var i=0; i < products[category].length; i++) {
        for(var l=0; l < products[i].length; l++) {
            for (var b=0; b < i[category][l].length; b++) {
                console.log('Name: '+ i[category][l][0]);
                console.log('Price: '+i[category][l][2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note the above code is only for an example. It should function all right but I might have made a mistake while writing it. This was just to show my point.**

Comment: Thanks! But the question is how I can transform the dataset to this array/JSON!

Comment: @Robert You need something that would transform a table of data into an array?

Comment: Yes! But I dont need as I asked in the question! It means hierarchically.  Not as same in the Database! Hope you understand!

Comment: @Robert Yes I do. Might wanna host an SQL database. PHP can order the query results into an array.

Comment: I can convert the query results into an array, but  here the deal is to convert the normal query results into a tree kind of array. That means the repetitions should not be allowed.,

Comment: @Robert Oh. Hierarchy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75616/discussion-between-bytec0de-and-robert).

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a group by, isn't?

Try Linq. This is just an (untested) approach, but can give you an ideia where to start:

```
var results = from c in dataset
              group c by c.Category into cGrouped
              select new {
                 Category = cGrouped.Category,
                 Items = from i in cGrouped
                         group i by i.Item into iGrouped
                         select new {
                            Item = iGrouped.Item
                            Colors = from cl in iGrouped
                                     group cl by cl.Color into clGrouped
                                     select new {
                                        Color = cl.Color
                                     }
                         }
              };
```

Then return the json using Json ActionResult of controller:

```
return Json(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Json.NET framework to transform a DataSet to a JSON string.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

DataTable MyData = new DataTable();

string Output = "";
Output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyData, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do a merge.  I realize that you may be doing this in C#, and I'm going to show you the answer in Javascript, but we know that C# has arrays and HashMaps and a JSONSerializer class, so this should serve as reasonable pseudocode.

```
var data = [
    ['Electronics', 'Mobile', 'Black'],
    ['Electronics', 'Mobile', 'Green'],
    ['Electronics', 'Laptop', 'Black'],
    ['HomeNeeds', 'VaccumCleaner', 'white'],
    ['HomeNeeds', 'Refigerator', 'Red'],
    ['Wearable', 'AppleWatch', 'Red']
];

function force(collection, key) {
    if (!collection[key]) collection[key] = {};
    return collection[key];
}

function tableToTree(data) {
    var result = {};
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        force(force(result, item[0]), item[1]).color = item[2];
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tableToTree(data)));
```

The trick is simple... whatever the language, you need to be able to say...

```
result[category][item]["color"] = color;
```

...without anything barking at you.  And then you can use one of the available JSON serializers.  The code should be easy to read, even if it isn't the absolute most performant bit of code.

If speed is important, or you'll be doing this a lot, building a collection only to serialize and deconstruct it is expensive.  Invest a bit of time writing a JSON encoder for your object which will do the popping and pushing and comparing and will append strings as it works through your collection.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities: 1. do it yourself, 2. let the database do the work

1. For a result set as shown in the question (`select col1, col2, ... order by col1, col2, ...`) you can just parse it in the following way:

   ```
   === simplified algorithm in pseudo code ===
   init old column values to a unique value (e.g. null if not used)
   loop over the result set:
      test the columns from left to right:
      if old column X <> column X
         add column X and all values to the right to the datastructure
   ```
2. Here is how you could write a query that exactly gives you the structure using list aggregations (`LISTAGG()` in orale and `GROUP_CONCAT()` in mySQL):

   ```
   SELECT
     '{' ||
       LISTAGG(O.S, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY O.S) ||
     '}'
   FROM
     (SELECT
       O.Category Category, -- (*)
       '{"' || O.Category '":[' ||
         LISTAGG(O.S, ',')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY O.S) ||
         ']}'
       S
     FROM
       (SELECT
         T.Category Category,
         T.Item Item, -- (*)
         '{"' || T.Item || '":[' ||
           LISTAGG('{"color":"' || T.Color || '"}', ',')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.Color) ||
           ']}'
         S
       FROM
         Table T
       GROUP BY
         T.Category, T.Item
       ORDER BY
         T.Category, T.Item  
       ) O
     GROUP BY
       O.Category
     ORDER BY
       O.Category
     ) O
   ;

   -- (*) probably required because of GROUP BY
   ```

Comment: I am  not sure if this helps you, because we don't know exactly where the data comes from i.e. its original form, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

For example say the query returned from database is like this (each row, only something we need for here)

```
var row = {'Category': 'value', 'Item': 'value', 'Color': 'value'}
```

you just need this code in javascript:

First of all build an empty  object like:

```
var object = {} or window.object = {}
```

then call this code in your foreach or any where you get each row value

```
if(object['Category'] == undefined)
  object['Category'] = {}
if(object['Category'][row['Category']] == undefined)
  object['Category'][row['Category']] = {}
if(object['Category'][row['Category']][row['Item']] == undefined)
  object['Category'][row['Category']][row['Item']] = []
object['Category'][row['Category']][row['Item']].push({
    ['Color'] : {[row['Color']]
})
```

i did make one change, only the last part is array rest is object, hope its helpful, all this line means something like this

```
object['Category'][row['Category']][row['Item']].push({['Color'] : {[row['Color']]})
```

you just need to be sure if they are exist don't build them again